# record counter in go-mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to implement record_nbr in mongo collection. I have searched Stackoverflow and there doesn't seems any straight forward way have a field in document which depicts the sequence number of this particular document in collection.

The code below is good to implement counter within document of collection but how to implement document counter number in collection?

```
    opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(true)
    filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: TransactionID}}
    update := bson.D{{"$inc", bson.D{{"record_number", 1}}}}
    _, err = db.Collection("transaction").UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update, opts)
```

expected behaviour required

```
[{
   "_id": "61f81309936f24de43b4e799",
   "record_nbr": 2
},
{
   "_id": "61f81309936f24de43b4e0j8",
   "record_nbr": 3
},
{
   "_id": "f8f24de43b4e0j81309936op",
   "record_nbr": 4
}]
```

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have support for this. You have to implement this yourself, e.g. keeping a counter somewhere (some collection some document), increment that, and use its value when inserting / updating documents.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you're looking for a way to order documents by insertion order by tracking the record number, you can sort by _id which is a monotonically increasing number. If you're looking to create your own document ID scheme using this record number, that would have to be implemented by hand.